# Cant Create Facebook Ad via Ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to create a Facebook AD via their PHP SDK. The problem lies in the creation of the ad itself. If I comment out the last piece, its creates  the adset. When I run this code, I get the error **"a Parent ID is required"**

```
try {   

///////////////////////////// CREATE AD SET ////////////////////////////////////
$data = array(
AdSetFields::NAME => $adname,
AdSetFields::BID_TYPE => 'CPC',
AdSetFields::BID_INFO => array(
'CLICKS' => 6,
),
AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_STATUS => AdSet::STATUS_PAUSED,
AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => 500000,
AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID => $campaign_id,
AdSetFields::TARGETING => array(
 'age_min' => 30,
'age_max' => 45,
'page_types' => array(
    'desktopfeed',
  ),
'geo_locations' => array(
  'countries' => array(
    'US',
     ),      
    ),
  ),
);
     $adset = new AdSet(null, $account_id);
    $adset->create($data);

 $adset_id = $adset->id;
echo $adset_id.'-';


//////////////////////CREATE AD IMAGE ///////////////////////////////


$image = new AdImage(null, $account_id);
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = '../adimages/epsom.jpg';
$image->create();

$creative = new AdCreative(null, $account_id);
$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $adtitle,
  AdCreativeFields::BODY => $addesc,
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL => $tracking_promoted_url,
  AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $image->hash,
));
$creative->create();

echo $creative->id.'-';

/////////////////////////////// CREATE AD GROUP ////////////////////////////

$fields = array(array(
  AdGroupFields::CREATIVE => 
    array('creative_id' => $creative->id),
    AdGroupFields::ADGROUP_STATUS => AdGroup::STATUS_PAUSED,
  AdGroupFields::NAME => 'My First AdGroup',
  AdGroupFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $adset_id,
));
$ad = new AdGroup();
$ad->create($fields);

echo 'AdGroup ID:' . $adgroup->id . "-";


} catch (RequestException $e) {
     echo 'Caught Exception: '.$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL
   .'Code: '.$e->getCode().PHP_EOL
.'HTTP status Code: '.$e->getHttpStatusCode().PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Is that error from somewhere in that SDK or from the API itself? Are you sure you're setting the Ad Set ID correctly on the Ad before trying to create it?

Comment: that is what the api returns. i echo the adset id to make sure it was creating it, and it seemed to output it. below is the error  <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'A parent ID is required.' in /.../src/FacebookAds/Object/AbstractCrudObject.php:125
Stack trace:

Comment: Can you share more of your code? I wonder if or how you're setting up the Ads SDK. For instance, are you calling Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token); and $api = Api::instance(); per the docs? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk

Comment: yes, i am intializing the api... like i said, when i remove the last piece of the code (the adgroup) then it creates the adset with no ad.

Comment: I don't see anywhere after you do `$ad = new AdGroup();` where you set the ad set ID- are you missing that? (`campaign_id` is a required field (and is the Ad Set ID, but named `campaign_id` for legacy reasons)): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adgroup/v2.3#syncadgroupcreation

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parent ID parameter when you create the adgroup. The 2nd parameter should be the account ID you want to create this adgroup under:

```
$adgroup = new Adgroup(null, $accountId);
```

If you copied this from a doc, let me know and we can update.

Answer (score 0):

You may reference to the latest doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign

From there, you will need to specify the ad account id(AD_ACCOUNT_ID) and ad campaign id(CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID)